# what is the waveform difference between primary and secondary of transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, waveform

I am talking about the autotransfomer. I am wondering how would the waveform be different is if I measure the Voltage at primary side, versus measuring voltage at secondary side.

**Is the general voltage waveform shape the same and it's only a scaling factor of difference between the primary and secondary side ?**

[image]

Notice that in the photo, I am only using the 120V on primary. On the other input voltage, I dont use them (not connecting to any power supply)

Comment: Are you asking how does an autotransformer convert voltage in a same winding?

Comment: Yes, does it only scale down the voltage waveform by a factor ? Or does the voltage waveform shape be the same (only scaling difference) between primary and secondary ?

Comment: The magnetic field that gets wound up with your primary current is shared higher up by the secondary winding. Magnetic fields cause electrons to move inducing a voltage. Since your primary voltage is fixed by your power company, the voltage at the top of the winding must be higher. Because the circuits on an auto transformer are electrically connected. They are less isolated and you are more sensitive to load impedance

Answer (score 1):

Hii it is ballast auto transformer. So induction is major role. You can refer to BL Theraja for better understanding.

Ideally no any change in input & out waveform for resistive load. But practically some induction & capacitive parameters are included from load side. So inductive load will give some distortion & reduce the power factor while capacitor will boost your power factor.

So output wave form will be distorted according to your load inductance & capacitance.